# moving an object in a striaght line

Tags: android

i have to make an application in which on every click it should throw an object and that object should travel in a straight line. I am done with creating an object on every click. But how to move an object in a straight line at the time when i click. any example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At any given time `t` your object has a position `(x, y)`.  It is also moving with a velocity vector `(v_x, v_y)`.

After a change in time of `dt`, if you can assume that your object is moving with constant velocity over the entire time interval, you can calculate a new position like this:

```
dx = v_x*dt;
dy = v_y*dt;
x += dx;
y += dy;
t += dt;
```

If that constant velocity assumption is bad, it means you need to reduce `dt` until it's close enough to true.